# TinyMce wiht AtD spell check not work correctly in Chrome, please guide?

Tags: asp.net, tinymce

In my asp.net site I have TinyMce editor and for spell checking I have included AtD (after the deadline) spellcheck plugin in it.

In Chrome there is a problem this AtD spell check plug in has damaged TinyMce controls functionality. I can not use TinyMce features (like font size family change etc.) in Chrome but it works fine in other browsers. Any guidance will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the regular spellcheck plugin together with either google spellchecker or Aspell/Ispell?

**Edit (added):**

[Here is a linkt o a HOWTO.](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin%3aspellchecker) It describes well how the spellchecker plugin can be configured and what needs to be done.

Comment: thanks for this suggestion. I have asp.net site where I am using this, can you please give some details on how to use regular spellcheck plugin ? 

If I am not mistaken regular spellcheck plugin works only with IE ? PLeae guide.

Comment: no the regular spellcheck plugin can be configured to work with a variety of spellcheckers (located on a server) and should work on all major browsers